# lemma is true for separated locally convex space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Lemma 1.3. in [Probability Distributions on Banach Spaces](https://books.google.com/books?id=JtLyCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&dq=Let+X+be+a+non-separable+metric+space.+Then+there+exists+an+uncountabLe+subset&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju6sOV48TUAhULVhQKHWlPAzQQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=Let%20X%20be%20a%20non-separable%20metric%20space.%20Then%20there%20exists%20an%20uncountabLe%20subset&f=false) by
N. N. Vakhania , V. 1. Tarieladze and
S. A. Chobanyan, say Let $X$ be a non-separable metric space. Then
there exists an uncountable subset $D\subset X$ such that: 
$\inf\Big\{ p(x,y): x,y \in D, x \neq y \Big\} $$ > 0$.

Now my question is, the above lemma is true for separated locally convex space $E$?